# Joining to another table only on the first occurrence of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Note: I have tried to simplify the below to make it simpler both for me and for anyone else to understand, the tables I reference below are in fact sub-queries joining a lot of different data together from different sources)

I have a table of purchased items:

**Items**

```
ItemSaleID CustomerID  ItemCode
1          100         A
2          100         B
3          100         C
4          200         A
5          200         C
```

I also have transaction header and detail tables coming from a till system:

**TranDetail**

```
TranDetailID  TranHeaderID  ItemSaleID  Cost
11            51            1           $10
12            51            2           $10
13            51            3           $10
14            52            4           $20
15            52            5           $10
```

**TranHeader**

```
TranHeaderID  CustomerID Payment Time
51            100        $100    11:00
52            200        $50     12:00
53            100        $20     13:00
```

I want to get to a point where I have a table like:

```
ItemSaleID CustomerID  ItemCode   Cost   Payment Time
1          100         A          $10    $120    11:00
2          100         B          $10            11:00
3          100         C          $10            11:00
4          200         D          $20    $50     12:00
5          200         E          $10            12:00
```

I have a query which produces the results but when I add in the `ROW_NUMBER()` case statement goes from 2 minutes to 30+ minutes.

The query is further confused because I need to supply the earliest date relating to the list of transactions and the total price paid (could be many transactions throughout the day for upgrades etc)

Query below:

```
SELECT ItemSaleID
     , CustomerID
     , ItemCode
     , Cost 
     , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TranHeaderID ORDER BY ItemSaleID) = 1
            THEN TRN.Payment ELSE NULL END AS Payment

FROM Items I

OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT TOP 1 SUB.Payment, Time
             FROM TranHeader H
             INNER JOIN TranDetail D ON H.TranHeaderID = D.TranHeaderID

             OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(Payment) AS Payment
                          FROM TranHeader H2
                          WHERE H2.CustomerID = Items.CustomerID
                         ) SUB

             WHERE D.CustomerID = I.CustomerID


            ) TRN

WHERE ...
```

Is there a way that I can only show payments for each occurrence of the customer ID whilst maintaining performance

Comment: There's no ROW_COUNT in SQL Server, you probably mean ROW_NUMBER? What are the relations between those tables/queries? 1:1, 1:many, many:many?

Comment: @dnoeth Yes sorry I meant `ROW_NUMBER()` will edit, relations are Many Item to Many TranHeaders to Many TranDetails.

Comment: I usually don't work with SQL Server, so i'm not very used to OUTER APPLY (especially nested ones), but in most cases it can be replaced with some Windowed Aggregate Functions (you tagged the question with SS2012). E.g. all the rows from the header table including the sum of all payments of a customer and the earliest time can be easily calculated using `SELECT H.*, SUM(H.Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) AS payment,
   MIN(time) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) AS minTime
FROM TranHeader AS H`